# Why cout the pointer can change the data

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void reset(int *a, int *b){
    int sum = *a + *b;
    *a = (sum / 2.0 - sum / 2) >= 0.5 ? sum / 2 + 1 : sum / 2;
    *b = *a;
    cout << hex << (void *)a<<endl;
    cout << hex << b<<endl;
}
int main(){
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    reset(&a, &b);
    cout << a <<' '<< b << endl;
}
```

I use the code to reset two variable,but after I print the pointers of variable,the data changed.When I commente the two cout statement.It works.
Looks like this:
[image: cout the pointer]

[image: not cout the pointer]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return to `dec`, because you changed the output to `hex`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void reset(int *a, int *b){
    int sum = *a + *b;
    *a = (sum / 2.0 - sum / 2) >= 0.5 ? sum / 2 + 1 : sum / 2;
    *b = *a;
    cout << hex; //set hex for output stream
    cout << (void *)a<<endl;
    cout << b<<endl;
    cout << dec; // return to dec system
}
int main(){
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    reset(&a, &b);
    cout << a <<' '<< b << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you write `cout << hex;` Then you change the output to write always values in hex. So to return into decimal system you have to write `cout << dex`. Please check the documentation of [std::hex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) . @Mateusz-Grzejek also described it more deeply below.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not modified, you change `basefield` *format flag* after using [std::hex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) here:

```
cout << hex << (void *)a << endl;
cout << hex << b << endl;
```

That's why commenting this out "fixes" this "problem".

You can uncomment this call, but modify you `reset()` function, so it will restore original stream state:

```
void reset(int *a, int *b)
{
    int sum = *a + *b;
    *a = (sum / 2.0 - sum / 2) >= 0.5 ? sum / 2 + 1 : sum / 2;
    *b = *a;

    cout.setf(std::ios::hex); //Print as hexadecimal numbers

    cout << (void *)a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;

    cout.setf(std::ios::dec); //Restore to decimal
}
```

I modified your reset to set `hex` only once instead of doing `<< hex` every time you print something (although it is not necessary, because, as you noticed, stream is modified permanently - that's why I prefer explicit functions call).

Further read: [std::ios_base::setf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf).